# Why is the set of k-forms $\Omega^{k}(\varnothing)=0$?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, homology-cohomology, de-rham-cohomology

I'm studying cohomology theory from Loring W. Tu- An introduction to Manifolds. And in the construction of the Mayer-Vietoris Sequence, we take a manifold $M$ and an open cover $\left\{U,V\right\}$ of $M$. So in the Mayer-Vietoris Sequence, appears the cohomology group associated to the vector space $\Omega^{k}(U\cap V)$ of the differential forms of degree $k$ on the manifold $U\cap V$. BUT, if $U\cap V=\varnothing$ then is a convention that $\Omega^{k}(U\cap V)=0$. Why this convention works?. Why if we adot this convention we will find the right results and conclusions in calculating the cohomology groups of a manifold?. Depending on the definition we are using, the empty set is not a manifold, so the set of k-forms on it does not make any sense. Please, someone can clarify this for me? Thanks!

Comment: It's the same idea that $\varnothing$ is a basis for the zero vector space $\{\mathbf{0}\}$.

Comment: The empty set should certainly be a manifold in its own right. Then, any vector bundle over the empty set comes with a map to the empty set, so necessarily is the empty set as well. There is one and only one section of the identity map on the empty set, which is itself the identity on the empty set, and this is the space of $k$-forms. The vector space structure on a space with one element is necessarily the trivial one.